# How to add addon in razor files?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to create an addon so that user enters only a facebook profile name, instead of the whole url.
Current razor code to get input looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Twitter, new {@class = "control-label"})
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Twitter, new {@class = "form-control"})
</div>
```

And this is what I have tried:

```
<div class="form-group">                    
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Facebook, new { @class = "control-label" }
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">
                                    facebook.com
    </span>
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Facebook, new {@id="basic-addon2"})                                    
</div>
```

But it creates a wrong form like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449580/twitterbootstrap-input-groups-with-razor-syntax)
What do I need to modify in order to get an addon correctly?
like: facebook.com/ {input-filed}

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="facebook-profile">facebook.com/</span>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Facebook, new { @class="form-control", placeholder="Profile Name", aria_describedby="facebook-profile">
</div>
```